# CSS z-index property doesn't work

Tags: css, z-index, css-filters

I'm trying to give an hover effect to a div (a background picture) with the "filter" property. But it has got an influence on another div (my text) which is supposed to be over.
I applied the z-index property (without forgetting the position of my divs) but it doesn't work. You'll see, my text is blurring too and is not supposed to. Could you tell me please what's wrong with my code ?

Here is the codepen showing my problem : https://codepen.io/Gillian-D/pen/qmqEQy

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6 left_part-padding">
         <div class="left_part">
           <div class="left_part_content">
             Left part
          </div>
         </div>
     </div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}


.left_part {
  height: 40vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  background-image: url(img/book2.jpeg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 50px 60px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.35);
  border-radius: 10px;
}


.left_part:hover {
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
filter: blur(5px);
-webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
position: relative;
z-index:0;
}

.left_part_content:hover {
color: #fed136;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
}

.left_part-padding, .right_part-padding, .bottom_part-padding {
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
}

.left_part_content {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Raleway", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: .300em;
  margin-right: -.300em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 40vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The blur property blur all the element and children, you can't make what you want in this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add an effect on an element, in most cases their children gets affected as well, so in this case, you could use a pseudo element for the `background-image`

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmNpbG)

Changed CSS rules

```
.left_part {
  height: 40vh;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 50px 60px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.35);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.left_part::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/200/nature/1/);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.left_part:hover::before {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EmNPVZ

I took the text part element out of the to-be-blurred background div, now both have the same parent. Next I solved the centering differently, the usual way (absolute position, top and left 50%, `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`. I then applied `pointer-events: none;` to the text layer so the hover below it could word. And I added a different hover rule that affects the text - see my codepen. HTH